# Sql Mathematical calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some database tables with corresponding values. Now I want to make "sum" of the columns. Whenever I try to do that it produces the error **"Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator"**. I have 4 columns with varchar(100) as its datatype.

Comment: Please show us your query.

Comment: Why are you storing numeric values in `varchar` columns? (And if they are not numeric why are you trying to `SUM` them?)

Comment: Thank you Martin Smith. Its all the values are numeric. But i used varchar. So that i want know why it produce the error and how to clear.

Comment: @ArunkumarMurugesan - So you should change the column datatype to something more appropriate then. Storing numbers as strings is space inefficient, means you need to cast all the time, and sooner or later you will end up with invalid data.

Comment: Yes. sure Martin. but now i clear that..

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error message is pretty clear.  The idea of "summing" strings just doesn't make sense.  If numbers are really being stored in a string representation, just use cast:

```
select sum(cast(column as float))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Gordon Linoff. Now its working. I stored all the values as numberic, i can use integer datatype. But i used varchar. May i know why we are using float datatype..

Comment: @ArunkumarMurugesan . . . Because you don't specify what the numbers look like.  `float` is more general than `int` or `unsigned`.  If the numbers are integers, then cast to the appropriate type.  Better, fix the table so the data is stored as the right type.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.. Thank you once again..

Comment: For using your answer i got the output. Now i use the average of the same & getting the result as 3.80282051282051.. Is there any possibilities to getting minimized rounded value like 3.80 like that. thanks in advance..

Comment: @ArunkumarMurugesan . . . Try casting to a decimal type, such as `decimal(15, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this then for rounded answer

```
select Round(sum(cast(column as float)),2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much DhruvJoshi. Now its working. I think this is normal thing. but i'm the beginner in that. thank you again.